# Using Dispose in Pascal

Tags: pointers, pascal, freepascal

Let's say I have a linked list in Pascal. The type would look something like this:

```
type
  PList = ^TList;
  TList = record
          x: integer;
          Next: PList;
          end;

var
  myList :PList;
```

So if I use `dispose(myList)` are then disposed all pointers in myList? Or just a first one pointing on the first element of myList?

Comment: In this case you are disposing only the variable that you've allocated, so only the `myList`.

Comment: So I would have a memory leak? Because all other pointers are still there pointing on some data?

Comment: Yes. That would produce a memory leak. Disposed that way would be managed types, e.g. record (not a pointer to a record), or e.g. an array of records, but not anything what's *behind a pointer*. In simple words, `Dispose` will dispose everything what `New` allocated.

Comment: And one more question, how would I manage to dispose my whole list? Something like `dispose(myList^)`?

Comment: keep a copy of the next pointer, dispose the first record. Now the copy of the next pointer is the new first pointer etc.

Comment: See [computer-programming-forum.com: Pascal, Disposing linked lists](http://computer-programming-forum.com/29-pascal/aaa2df9288ebad02.htm)

Comment: Note- to apply Dispose, myList type should be PList, not TList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, disposing of `myList` (which should be of type `PList` by the way) will only dispose of the first item in the list. That's because the compiler knows *nothing* about how you're *using* the individual fields in the record.

For example you may be using a skip list or doubly linked list, both of which would require *two* pointers within the record.

The way to dispose of an entire list is as follows.

```
    var myList, listPtr, nextPtr : PList;
    :
    listPtr := myList;            (* start at start, obviously *)
    myList := nil;                (* mark list as empty        *)
    while listPtr <> nil do       (* continue until end        *)
    begin
        nextPtr := listPtr^.next; (* save pointer to next      *)
        dispose (listPtr);        (* kill current              *)
        listPtr := nextPtr;       (* move to next              *)
    end;
```

The reason you need to save a pointer to the next record is because, once you dispose of the current one, you're not allowed to access its fields. So you have to save it *before* the `dispose`.

This can be seen in the following complete program, which constructs a two element list, prints it, the disposes of the entire list.

```
Program TestProg(output);
    type
        PList = ^TList;
        TList = record
            num : integer;
            next: PList;
        end;

    var
        myList  : PList;
        listPtr : PList;
        nextPtr : PList;
begin
    (* Construct list 42 -> 99 -> 12 -| *)

    new (myList);
    new (myList^.next);
    new (myList^.next^.next);
    myList^.next^.next^.next := nil;

    myList^.num := 42;
    myList^.next^.num := 99;
    myList^.next^.next^.num := 12;

    (* Traverse list *)

    listPtr := myList;
    while listPtr <> nil do
    begin
        writeln (listptr^.num);
        listPtr := listPtr^.next;
    end;

    (* Clear list *)

    listPtr := myList;
    while listPtr <> nil do
    begin
        nextPtr := listPtr^.next;
        dispose (listPtr);
        listPtr := nextPtr;
    end;
    myList := nil;
end.
```